# Parsing Array from a website using JSON in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to parse a particular Array from the data given below, specifically Solar:

```
{
  "Month":
        {"1":"January",
         "2":"February",
         "3":"March",
         "4":"April",
         "5":"May",
         "6":"June",
         "7":"July",
         "8":"August",
         "9":"September",
         "10":"October",
         "11":"November",
         "12":"December"},
  "Air":
        {"1":"26.6",
         "2":"26.9",
         "3":"27.2",
         "4":"27.6",
         "5":"27.6",
         "6":"27.1",
         "7":"26.7",
         "8":"26.5",
         "9":"26.5",
         "10":"26.8",
         "11":"26.7",
         "12":"26.4"},
  "Humid":
        {"1":"79.5%",
         "2":"75.6%",
         "3":"75.8%",
         "4":"75.9%",
         "5":"77.5%",
         "6":"78.2%",
         "7":"79.0%",
         "8":"81.5%",
         "9":"80.5%",
         "10":"77.2%",
         "11":"76.7%",
         "12":"79.7%"},
  "Solar":
        {"1":"5.87",
         "2":"6.51",
         "3":"6.77",
         "4":"6.42",
         "5":"5.51",
         "6":"4.86",
         "7":"4.95",
         "8":"5.09",
         "9":"5.92",
         "10":"6.22",
         "11":"6.12",
         "12":"5.82"},
  "Atm":
        {"1":"101.1",
         "2":"101.1",
         "3":"101.1",
         "4":"101.0",
         "5":"101.0",
         "6":"101.0",
         "7":"101.1",
         "8":"101.1",
         "9":"101.2",
         "10":"101.2",
         "11":"101.2",
         "12":"101.2"},
  "Wind":
        {"1":"3.7",
         "2":"3.9",
         "3":"3.0",
         "4":"2.9",
         "5":"3.7",
         "6":"4.0",
         "7":"3.5",
         "8":"3.7",
         "9":"3.0",
         "10":"3.7",
         "11":"3.9",
         "12":"3.4"},
  "Earth":
        {"1":"28.5",
         "2":"28.6",
         "3":"29.3",
         "4":"30.0",
         "5":"29.9",
         "6":"29.5",
         "7":"29.3",
         "8":"29.0",
         "9":"29.1",
         "10":"28.9",
         "11":"28.5",
         "12":"28.4"},
  "HDD":
        {"1":"0",
         "2":"0",
         "3":"0",
         "4":"0",
         "5":"0",
         "6":"0",
         "7":"0",
         "8":"0",
         "9":"0",
         "10":"0",
         "11":"0",
         "12":"0"},
  "CDD":
        {"1":"514",
         "2":"477",
         "3":"532",
         "4":"529",
         "5":"545",
         "6":"511",
         "7":"516",
         "8":"509",
         "9":"495",
         "10":"519",
         "11":"502",
         "12":"509"}
}
```

I am trying to understand how to do that using different tutorials but I cannot seem to move on. I just need to extract that `JSONArray` and convert it into a `String` Array and store these values to variables. Now, I am able to get this far:

```
public JSONObject solardata() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(URL);
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(sb.toString());
    HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
    int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (status == 200) {
        HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
```

What should I do after this? How can I fetch `JSONArray`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Google is your friend. Please search before you ask. A simple search for "android httpget json" will give you tons of examples. [Here's](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) the first hit that does exactly what you want.
2. There is not Array in your JSON. It is merely a normal JSON object with keys and values.

Comment: So tell me how can I extract the key "Solar" and its Values?

Comment: I have followed a number of tutorials, but I always get stuck because I do not have the basic concept of JSON. If anyone can help me with this, I'd be very grateful to him/her.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a JSON array should look like this.-

```
{
    results:[
        elem1,
        elem2,
        ...
    ]
}
```

So first off, you have to make sure you're getting a JSON in the form you're expecting. Once you have a `String` with a valid JSON array, you can retrieve it with something like this.-

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i ++) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    // Do whatever you need with obj
}
```

You can find a bunch of good tutorials, take [this one](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by this way:

```
   try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                statusCode = -1;
                Log.e("log_tag", "Erro http " + e.toString());
            }
if (statusCode == 200) {

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Erro conversão " + e.toString());
            }

            try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray monthsJSON = json.getJSONArray("Months");
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> monthsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < monthsJSON.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) monthsJSON.get(i);
                HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String index = String.valueOf(i+1);
                data.put(index, object.getString(index));
                monthsList.add(data);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Erro dados " + e.toString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Except that Month is not an array. You have to get it as a JSONObject and then iterate over the keys.

Comment: I know Month is not an array, but how can I get it as a JSONObject and iterate?

Answer (score 0):

this my simple JSON.

```
yourJson :
[
 {"id":"1","name":"Jhohannes H Purba","address":"Kabanjahe"},
 {"id":"2","name":"Berkat Junaidi Banurea","address":"Sidikalang"},
 {"id":"3","name":"Totok BluesMan Silalahi","address":"Medan"}
]
```

For insert field to array, i use this

```
            JSONArray arrayJson = new JSONArray(yourJson);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLagu.length(); i++) {    
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = arrayLagu.getJSONObject(i);
                int id = jsonChildNode.optInt("id");
                String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                String address = jsonChildNode.optString("address");

                arrayId.add(i, id);
                arrayJudul.add(i, name);
                arrayLirik.add(i, address);
            }
```